# Error : Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in

Tags: javascript

I have a table `book_hotel`, and I make `total_price` column using `sum()`. But it does not work. Anyone help me please?

So this my controller :

```
public function getHotelName(Request $req)
{
    $hotel_code = $req->hotel_id;
    $hotel = DB::table('book_hotel')->where('id_hotel', $hotel_code)->sum('hotel_total_price');
    echo json_encode($hotel);
}
```

My JavasSript :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
console.log( "ready!" );

  $('#total_price_hotel_id').on('change', function(){
    getInfoHotel(this.value)
  })
});

const showInfoHotel = function(ele) {
  $('#modalTotalPriceHotel').modal('show');
}
const getInfoHotel = function(hotelCode) {
  $.get(API.get.hotelname, {hotel_id: hotelCode}).done(function(response){
    const hotels = JSON.parse(response);
    if(hotels.length > 0) {
      $.each(hotels, function(index, data){
      $('#modalTotalPriceHotel #total_price_hotel').val(data);
      })
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: you probably dont need to check `if(hotels.length > 0)`, `$.each` wont run for 0 length

Comment: What part doesn't work?  Are you getting unexpected data or none at all? What error messages do you see, if any?   (My guess is that your `API.get.hotelname` isn't actually invoking your serverside `getHotelName` function, but that's just a guess as you haven't provided enough context to show whether that's the case.)

Comment: Also, what happens if your `getHotelName` does not match any `$hotelCode`?

Comment: yes , `if(hotels.length > 0)` does not work.

Comment: Your title says you are having problems with the `in` operator but none of your code uses that operator, nor do your address it in your actual question

Comment: it mean ```if(hotels.length > 0)``` does not work because have error : Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in
 and i don't know why :(

Comment: Have you checked to see what `hotels` actually contains at that point?